# Documentation for instance vs static method name paths in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

When documenting javascript methods, I am aware that using `#` in a name path denotes an instance method, like:

```
function Class() {}

/**
 * Class#method1
 */
Class.prototype.method1 = function () {}
```

However, I have also seen uses of `~` and `.`. What are those used for?

```
/**
 * Class~method2
 * Class.method3
 */
```

Are there other syntaxes that I should be aware of as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the details for variable/method naming conventions [here](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html#namepaths-in-jsdoc-3).

The `.` is used to denote a class method (also known as a static method), not an instance method. This means that on instances of the class (things created with `new`) you cannot call the class method.

Example:

```
Class.foo = function () {
  // ...
};

var blah = new Class();
blah.foo();  // throws an error

Class.foo();  // actually calls the function
```

The `~` is used to denote an *inner method* (also known as a private method), which is one defined inside a method of the class using `function`. These types of methods are not typically accessible from outside the method, so it is rare that you will see these documented.

Example:

```
function Class() {
  // this function is not accessible outside of the constructor
  function inner() {
  }

  // unless we give it some other reference that is visible:
  this.accessInner = inner;
}

blah = new Class();
blah.inner();        // throws an error
Class.inner();       // also throws an error
blah.accessInner();  // will actually call inner
```

Comment: Ah, it's described elsewhere in the documentation, I will update my answer with the details.

Comment: So would `accessInner` be documented as `Class.accessInner` or `Class~accessInner`

Comment: It would be `Class#accessInner`, since it is attached to the instance using `this`. In this case `Class#accessInner` and `Class~inner` would refer to the same method.

Comment: Ok great. I also just found this page which explains all the JSDoc name paths. http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html

Comment: Yup, I posted that link at the top of my answer ;)